# how to display data in gantt chart using amcharts in same object interval

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

Sorry to disturb your time. How can I show data in gantt chart

```
renderChartDenver() {
var chart = am4core.create("chartDenver", am4charts.XYChart);
    chart.data = [{
            "name": "John",
            "startTime": 8,
            "endTime": 11,
            "name_test":"mencium",
            "color": chart.colors.next()
          },{
            "name": "John",
            "startTime": 8,
            "endTime": 11,
            "name_test":"memandang",
            "color": chart.colors.next()
          },{
            "name": "John",
            "startTime": 9,
            "endTime": 15,
            "name_test":"merinding",
            "color": chart.colors.next()
          },{
            "name": "Joe",
            "startTime": 10,
            "endTime": 13,
            "name_test":"melihat",
            "color": chart.colors.next()
          }, {
            "name": "Susan",
            "startTime": 11,
            "endTime": 18,
            "name_test":"mendengar",
            "color": chart.colors.next()
          }, {
            "name": "Eaton",
            "startTime": 15,
            "endTime": 19,
            "name_test":"berdiri",
            "color": chart.colors.next()
          }];

      var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
      categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "name";
      categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
      categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

      var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
      valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

      var columnSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      columnSeries.dataFields.categoryY = "name";
      columnSeries.dataFields.valueX = "endTime";
      columnSeries.dataFields.openValueX = "startTime";
      columnSeries.columns.template.tooltipText = "[bold]{name}[/]\n starts at {openValueX}\nends at {valueX}";

      var columnTemplate = columnSeries.columns.template;
      columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 0;
      columnTemplate.propertyFields.fill = "color";
      columnTemplate.propertyFields.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
      columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;
      columnTemplate.height = am4core.percent(100);
}
```

when above code is running, will display below
    [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8edCB.png)

The Problem is :

The first object wasn't displayed. There should be 3 objects 
displayed with the property name "Jhon". why only show  two?

When I display it on gantt chart, the first object cannot display 
because it has the same start time and end time regarding to the 
second object.

The correct way is, I want all object with same name, 
startDate,endDate display in gant chart

Comment: I think that probably the first object is cover by 2nd object, so you have to find anothe way to  show the cases of  overlap, I think that isn't problem of the chart, maybe you need another kind of chart, in order to cover the cases of ovelap

Comment: thank you @Cyberguille. But I think the most suitable is the Gantt chart, or can you give amcharts recommendations that are suitable for the above problem

Comment: I think that you need also add a fragment of your code regarding with this Chart

Comment: Sorry maybe you misunderstood me, what I mean is that you put a short fragment of you code in javascript where you create this object and add the data to show.

Comment: @Cyberguille, thaks for your reply. I have update my question and code. my problem hasn't solved. thankyou